# PostGIS TopologyException

Tags: postgis

I have issues of topology errors in several big postGIS datasets.

```
create table out_table as select st_union(st_makevalid(geom)) from InTable where st_isvalid(geom) ;
```

I got :

```
ERROR:  GEOSUnaryUnion: TopologyException: found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING (86413.6 399070, 86413.6 399070) and LINESTRING (86413.6 399070, 86413.6 399070) at 86413.606740907679 399070.20461758168
```

The datasets correspond to agricultural parcels delimitation (multipolygons) and, in most cases, are derived from human draw. I think this is the reason why there are many errors.

I also tried solutions using `st_union(st_buffer(geom,0))` or `st_union(st_simplify(geom,0.01))` or `st_transform(st_union(st_transform(geom,4326)),EPSGout)`, as it can be found on other stackoverflow posts. Sometimes, one of this solution works but not systematically and I need a full automatic process with a reliable solution.

Any idea of a generic command that works whatever the datasets? To me `st_makevalid(geom)` should be THE solution but it does not work. Of course a solution that preserves all entities are preferable but I will accept a solution that discard entities with `TopologyException`

Thanks

**[EDIT-1]**

To complement, I found exactly my issue on another treat there => https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/4182#comment:8
An I am not been able to make the `safe_union` function, proposed by fengel, working

The only solution I found is using QGIS dissolve function which skip exceptions and just print a warnings. qgis is accessible with python and I think I will rely on that, even if I would prefer a postGIS solution

Comment: Hey Martin, can you add the data (e.g. as WKT) that is causing the problem and let us know in which SRS it is encoded?

Comment: Hi Jim - It is difficult to extract data at the specific location where there are exceptions. please find here the entire dataset https://www.dropbox.com/s/n42yma4z15b6nxm/spl_2020.gpkg?dl=1
the SRS is EPSG:28992